# Multi-step traversal in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, traversal, graph-databases

I have a data structure where data is composed of two sorts of nodes: `item` and `claim`. `claim` represents some information about the item and may refer to other items, such as - certain entity being located in certain other entity, e.g. "Germany is in Europe". Example structure:

```
create 
(v1:item {id:"Q1", name: "Europe"}),
(v2:item {id:"Q2", name: "France"}),
(v3:item {id:"Q3", name: "Germany"}),
(v4:item {id:"Q4", name: "Bavaria"}),
(v5:item {id:"Q5", name: "Munich"}),
(c1:claim:located),
(c2:claim:located),
(c3:claim:located),
(c4:claim:located),
(v5)-[:claim]->c4,
(c4)-[:located]->v4,
(v4)-[:claim]->c3,
(c3)-[:located]->v3,
(v3)-[:claim]->c2,
(c2)-[:located]->v1,
(v2)-[:claim]->c1,
(c1)-[:located]->v1;
```

also in http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ncbom6. Now, if I wanted to traverse it - e.g. to figure out all items in Germany, or in Europe, how can I do this? Is it possible with Cypher in this model? I know there's something like `v1-[r:*]->v2` but this assumes either one specific relationship or any relationship, and I need a repeating pattern of `claim-located` pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find, for example, all the items in Europe, using the data in your console:

```
MATCH (v:item { name: "Europe" })<-[:claim|located*]-(x:item)
RETURN x;
```

If you also want to ensure that the path traversed strictly alternates between `claim` and `located` relationships, here is a somewhat tricky way to do that:

```
MATCH (v:item { name: "Europe" })<-[rel:claim|located*]-(x:item)
WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, x IN rel | CASE
             WHEN (s = 0 AND TYPE(x)= 'claim')
             THEN 1
             WHEN (s = 1 AND TYPE(x)= 'located')
             THEN 0
             ELSE NULL END )= 0
RETURN x;
```

You can modify the `WHEN` tests if you need additional checking.

Comment: That would work for the mini-data example I have provided, but of course this is not real data. `[:claim|located*]` as I understand would match any combination of claim and located, i.e. claim-claim-claim-claim, located-located-claim, etc. But is there a way to match specific sequence  "claim, then located, any number of times"?

Comment: I have simplified my second query.